# Correct way to ask after death

Tags: grammaticality

How about the sentence below? Is this correct way to say?

```
My deepest condolences. Let her soul RIP.
```

Comment: [My condolences. May she rest in peace.](http://work.chron.com/express-condolences-death-someones-family-9967.html). Read [this](https://www.everplans.com/articles/how-to-express-sympathy-what-to-say-and-what-not-to-say) too.

Comment: BTW, you should write **Is thit correct to say?** not **to ask**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. If you believe in souls, they're not resting. You'd have to speak of her as a whole. Also using RIP is quite informal; better to write it in whole.
I'd go with "May she rest in peace".